Не загружаются стили в браузер
После обновления пакетов проекта до новых версий перестали загружаться стили, их совсем нет в браузере. использую стили так:
    import styles from "../WrappersCommon.scss";
    ...
    <div className={styles["main-layout"]}>

в конфиге вебпака стоит их загрузка
       test: /.(scss)$/,
    use: [
      {
        loader: "css-loader",
        options: {
          modules: {
            localIdentName: "[path][name]__[local]--[hash:base64:5]",
          },
        },
      },
      {
        loader: "postcss-loader",
        options: {
          postcssOptions: {
            plugins: [postcssPresetEnv()],
          },
        },
      },
      "sass-loader",
    ],

В терминале ошибок нет, но и в браузере стили пропали:



благодарю за любую помощь
